# SXA renderings not displayed in placeholder

Tags: sxa, placeholders

I am using sitecore 9 with SXA 1.7, when creating package using siterocks and deploying it to another environment, the renderings are displayed in preview mode but when open page as anonymous user nothing is rendered and the placeholders are empty, Any suggestion how can i trouble shot this?

Comment: Did you try publishing the complete website?

Comment: 1. Check logs. Search for errors or warnings
 2. Clear cache. Do you have any caching options?